# In suiteCRM how does one get about changing the Address field country and state text fields to be dropdowns?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am developing a custom suite CRM module however I find the Address field limiting since it uses text fields for country and state fields.

I have tried researching it by following instructions on this site:

https://johndopenotes.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/sugarcrm-change-address-state-and-country-to-dropdown-menu/

However I am stuck at step 5 since my custom module does not have a metadata directory???

5. Go to /custom/modules/Leads/metadata and update editviewdefs.php. Look for this code:

   array (
               'name' => 'primary_address_street',
               'hideLabel' => true,
               'type' => 'Address',
               'displayParams' => 
               array (
                 'key' => 'primary',
                 'rows' => 2,
                 'cols' => 30,
                 'maxlength' => 150,
               ),
             ),
             1 => 
             array (
               'name' => 'alt_address_street',
               'hideLabel' => true,
               'type' => 'Address',
               'displayParams' => 
               array (
                 'key' => 'alt',
                 'copy' => 'primary',
                 'rows' => 2,
                 'cols' => 30,
                 'maxlength' => 150,
               ),
             ),

and update the type from Address to CustomAddress

```
array (
            'name' => 'primary_address_street',
            'hideLabel' => true,
            'type' => 'CustomAddress',
            'displayParams' => 
            array (
              'key' => 'primary',
              'rows' => 2,
              'cols' => 30,
              'maxlength' => 150,
            ),
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'alt_address_street',
            'hideLabel' => true,
            'type' => 'CustomAddress',
            'displayParams' => 
            array (
              'key' => 'alt',
              'copy' => 'primary',
              'rows' => 2,
              'cols' => 30,
              'maxlength' => 150,
            ),
          ),
```

Can someone please give me a pointer as to how I can make address field in my custom module dropdowns instead of text fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead to choosing Address type field you can use combination of multiple fileds. For an example for street address you can use (datatype:textField)

[image]

Similarly for city you can add a text filed. Now for state and country you can use dropdown and add dropdown list as per your need

[image]

And for zipcode you can use integer / text field as per your requirement.

Now to make state dependend to country you can use custom javascript / jquery in following way

1. Add a reference to the javascript file you are going to add at the
   end of custom/modules/<>/metadata/[edit|detail]viewdefs.php
   $viewdefs['Opportunities']['EditView']['templateMeta']['includes'] = array ( array ( 'file' => 'path/to/file/filename.js', ), );
2. Add the javascript file you want to include into the location you
   referenced above.
3. Quick Repair from the admin section, then browser refresh

Answer (score 1):

It should just be a case of updating the vardefs for the field so the type is set to enum and the options point to your dropdown list. Then run a repair and rebuild.

The guide you've linked to looks like it is creating a new field type, which I think is overkill.  It's also using Sugar logic to make the 2 lists dependent, but I'm not sure that's a feature in SuiteCRM.

Comment: It's very hit and miss on what is and what isn't, as Suite is an extension on top of the now dead SugarCRM.

Some sugar logic works, some doesn't.